# Magento 2 : Order/Invoice/Shipment Grid Data Not Migrate

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, magento2-migration-tool

I try to migrate data from Magento 1.9.3.7 to Magento 2.2.4 using data-migration-tool. I follow all steps provide here : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-data.html

All data migrate successfull except this.

- Order Grid Table
- Invoice Grid Table
- Shipment Grid Table
- Creditmemo Grid Table

I check into database of magento2, all the tables are empty.

Any one have idea what to do?

Comment: Try with  web tool.

Comment: Can you specify in detail.

Comment: Please go through  this link you get more idea, you can migrate particular order or other section for that you need to change some of code. I have using this tool in early stage of magento 2 https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/

Comment: @Yogesh that is another tool. I am using magento tool and other data are migrate successfully except above table. So I want to know what is wrong here.

Comment: Sorry for wired suggestion but its help me many time in past use both  tool on same project. One another way you can do Delta migration By CLI might be its help you.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, how did you fixed above issue ? I am getting same https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315000/delta-migration-not-migrating-some-tables-data/315016