# Delta migration not migrating some table's data

Tags: magento2, migration, delta-migration

I am doing delta migration and first delta migration failed to migrate some record for below tables.

- m2_cl_sales_flat_order_grid
- m2_cl_sales_flat_invoice_grid
- m2_cl_sales_flat_shipment_grid

In above tables column `processed` is 0

**Example**:

- Initial order in M1 - 100
- Using data migration, order in M2 - 100
- New order in M1 - 10
- Delta migration did for 105 to 110

**Grid order data is missed from 101-104**

Now when I run delta migration, it is migration new grid order data for new orders.

Is there any log available, where I can check issue ?

can I migrate them manually ?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I don't prefer the manual migration way, there is a high risk of unpredictable errors during the process. Try to find a Magento migration expert to help you perform the migration automatically and accurately. It can update the missed data by customization or run again the migration process.

Comment: @LitExtensionMagentoMigration, I am not migrating manually. I am using data migration tool form Magento. (data and delta) migration is working fine. only new grid data (sales, invoice, shipment ) is not migration in delta mode.

Answer (score 0):

For the new orders can you check if any new address,new customer or anything in the new orders of M1 which does not exist in M2 ?

Please have a look for this blog ..https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033020451?_ga=2.82099862.10141059.1592112318-519271195.1590997868

And You have initial migratin db of m2 that you did first time ?
You can log all errors generated during migration ..you faced any errors while doing delta migration ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am using same database for delta migration, issue is some of order grid data in NOT moving from M1 to M2. how can I manually move them ?